# convert raw data into ios application readable format

Tags: ios, data-structures

Am new to ios application development, but not to application development. Previously i created an android application, a part of it contains an array of **elements(say list heading)** and its corresponding description **(in another array)** i didn't have any trouble in retrieving those array elements and using them.

Requirements:

1. my project is not very complex to use SQLite datastores or Core Data.
2. i could have the data inside the application variable itself and use them as they are only used at the particular page.
3. i require a very simple solution to convert my existing data as said arrays.

Problem:
Now i would like to perform the same for ios application too. so i dont want to create the same array like structures redundantly.

Assumptions: 
Am assuming tat i could write a script to generate the arrays into an XML File and parse them and use them in my application.

So i need some suggestions and directions on my assumptions.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Is your question about how to store / persist data between app launches?

Comment: no let me be very confined. i need a tableview on each row click i need an alert view showing description. here i have an array for row text and another array for description. but the array is an java array  should i need to put the same array format or am thinking to generate an xml and parse it and update the content.

Comment: When you say it's a Java array, do you mean it is JSON?  Or do you mean the array is hard-coded in a separate app written in Java?

Comment: its an hard-coded array in separate application